# Creating/saving a shape key from moving a bone (Rig)

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

How can I create a shape key by moving the mesh's bone?

The bone I have selected will move the mouth mesh.
[image: The bone I have selected will move the mouth mesh.]
I moved it to the desired location.
[image: I moved it to the desired location.]
And now I want to save this changed mesh as a shape key, so the slider will activate it and change it back to normal when the value is 0.
[image: And now I want to save this changed mesh as a shape key, so the slider will activate it and change it back to normal when the value is 0.]

How can I save this final mesh as a shape key? The last picture will be the at the value of 1, and the first picture will be at the value of 0. Can I do this, without toggling Edit Mode, to create the shape key?

EDIT: Unless there's a way to save this pose (edited) in edit mode, I'll try to find another way to create this shape key.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this on a rigged mesh. I think the bone deformations will clash with the shapekey deformations. Someone might correct me on this.

Comment: Do you have another way of doing this? I'm trying to lip-sync it with words.

Comment: I know how to use shapekeys without bones. You just move the mesh by hand and then save the shapekey. You can mix shapekeys with bone movements, but I don't think you can save the bone deforms as shapekeys like you want to do. Again, I might be wrong (I have been at least once before).

Comment: Well, is there a way to save this mesh (edited) so it stays like this in edit mode? Until I switch it back?

Comment: If you have used bones to deform the mesh and now want to save that deformation, just use the PoseLib. You can save partial poses based on just the bones you select, so that you can save facial expressions as poses and then add them to other poses. I think that's the way you need to do this.

Comment: So I can save them in edit mode to create a shape key?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yeah. I just need to make the slider work.

Comment: There's a button under the shapekey panel that you need to click on to allow you to apply shapekeys in edit mode. It's beside the little pin button. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorta. I thought you had to do something with a driver. So, I create a shape key, and edit the mesh, then somehow save that mesh to apply as value 1 in edit mode. Somehow?

Comment: Normally, you create a shapekey in edit mode and then use it in object mode. You can test your shapekey in edit mode if that button is highlighted. No driver should be necessary.

Comment: i think you will be better served by using the pose library and creating different poses

Answer (score 10):

Select your mesh, go to the properties window, modifiers tab, in the armature modifier you'll find a button named "apply as shape key" wich does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, but how can I make the value/slider open and close his mouth, by changing the slider's value?

Comment: See my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

How I do it: To convert poses to shape keys,

First select your mesh in object mode, then click the little plus next to "shape keys" in the vertex panel; this creates a basis for your mesh, and it should say Basis or Base.

Then go in your armature's pose mode and create your pose.

Then in your meshes modifiers, click "Apply as shape key," this will remove your modifier so just recreate another armature modifier and set it to your armature again.

If you changed the location of the bones(not just rotation) for the shape key, the bones will displace their origin of manipulation if the shape key is used in conjunction with pose animation, as long as you do not use those bones in actual animations, you will be able to have scroll-able shape keys which work with the rest of the armature.

Also another tip for converting poses to edit mode without losing armature integrity,

Make your pose in pose mode, then normally apply the armature modifier on the mesh, open your armature's pose mode again and press "Ctrl-a" and click the first option, "apply pose as rest pose."  Then just reapply the armature modifier on the mesh.

Comment: Could you please post some pictures on this? Looks interesting but the switching order of object-armature-pose as shape, then what happens with the original Armature? This is what is confusing me. Could you please post pictures? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to blender. After I create my first shape key using this method, I'm unable to do it again. The bones in pose mode aren't connected to the meshes anymore. How do I "...recreate another armature modifier and set it to [my] armature again"?

Comment: This is not a typical forums so put this in the question section, or wait for the rep to go over 50 to comment.